# The spectrum of $(\alpha I + T)$, where $T$ is a compact operator, accumulates at $\alpha$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I am aware that the spectrum of a compact operator $T$ accumulates at $0$. Now say we have the operator $(\alpha I+ T)$ where $\alpha$ is some real number. I believe I read somewhere that the spectrum of this operator accumulates at $\alpha$ and this is desirable situation in numerical analysis as matrices will have better conditioning.

So how can it be shown that the spectrum of the operator $(\alpha I + T)$ accumulates at \alpha?

Comment: The spectral mapping theorem gives $\sigma(\alpha I+T)=\alpha+\sigma(T)$.

Comment: I think it is better to say that this follows directly from the definition of the spectrum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $\lambda\in\mathbb C$, 
$$
(\alpha I+ T) -\lambda I=T-(\lambda-\alpha)I.
$$
The above equality implies that $$\lambda\in\sigma(\alpha I+T)\iff \lambda-\alpha\in\sigma(T).$$
So $$ \sigma(\alpha I+T)=\alpha+\sigma(T).$$
In particular, when $T$ is compact, then spectrum of $\alpha I+T$ is either finite or it consists of a sequence that converges to $\alpha$.